# Last Section Header View not painted after insertRowForIndexpath and deleteRowForIndexpath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, sections

I have a setup with sections in a UITableView which all have a custom section header view. Only one section at a time can have visible rows.

To create an effect that displays other cell rows I basically use the following function:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

if ( sectionHeaderInsert >= 0 && sectionHeaderInsert <= numberOfSectionsInTableView ) {
    [ticketReastepsScreenView.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

[self updateTmpSelectedNumberToCurrent];

if ( sectionHeaderRemove >= 0 && sectionHeaderRemove <= numberOfSectionsInTableView ) {
    [ticketReastepsScreenView.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsRemove withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Now what happens is that in the end the new section "opens" and the old one "closes" propperly, but: if I have more sections that fit on the screen the last section that is (partly) visible will not repaint propperly - it is completely covered in white.

All sections are asked gor new heights and I think it even asks for new views (which I hae in an array). The views are then asked to [view setNeedsDisplay];

When I scroll a bit so that the last section header disappears and then scroll it back in, it comes to life again and is visible until I change the currently open section again.

**UPD**: This funny behavior only appears when I do the insertRow and deleteRow together. I can also simply close one section (deleteRow) and then in a section touch-action open the new one (insertRow) and the behavior is different.

I also tried having an endUpdates and beginUpdates in between the two actions - no positive result.

**UPD2**: When transitioning to the final position (positions are good) I can see the last section header being painted correctly, but then disappear (no animation, simple plain white over it)

Comment: try to programaticaly scroll the table view to the opened section

Comment: good idea - makes it more useable - but does not solve the problem. I think I found out in my layoutSubviews method of the custom section header views that the final updated size is 0,0,0,0 - which would make it invisible. How can that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the REAL problem was - I rewrote heavy parts of the TableView and I think what I've learned is:

If you need a UITableViewCell, use a UITableViewCell. If you need a UIView for the section headers, use a UIView for the section headers.

I've mixed the section headers with the TableViewCells just to re-use some code I had in there. Since categories can only extend one specific class I had to use delegation/provider methods/objects to re-use certain code. It may need more subclassing but is actually much safer.

In addition auto-scrolling to a position now works significantly better and the drawing artifacts are gone.

Comment: Except for one: If a cell at the top is open and I toggle one at the bottom, the header view of the toggled section will move down from the top - starting at 0,0. This is due to a frame update I suppose. But how can I stop this without saving the states?